# Magento Admin Ajax Loader

Tags: javascript, ajax, magento, prototypejs

I am using prototype Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater in the magento admin to get some data periodically . The javascript is in the head as I need to implement it on every page .

The issue is that Magento Loader is shown on every ajax request i.e. every two seconds in my case .

Is there any way that I can hide loader for my Ajax request in Magento admin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add **loaderArea:false** option.
Example:

```
new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('items', '/items', {
  method: 'get', frequency: 3, decay: 2,loaderArea:false
});
```